# Issues publishing my app as a web app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-for-education

Our organisation is using Google Apps for Edu and am scripting some things we usually do only from the administration app / console so I guess the script / app am developing will require privileged "permissions".

I have tried using all the combinations in the "Deploy as web app" screen (Publish => Deploy as web app), yet the app URL displays our Google Apps for Edu login screen, and I think it's because am doing admin stuff like UserManager.createUser().

I am wondering how the judges will now be able to access my app, or maybe am missing out something

Comment: What do you mean by 'yet the app URL displays our Google Apps for Edu login screen'? (note that I wasn't the 'downvote' author but still I don't really understand you question...)

Answer (score 0):

What are the 'some things' ? The security model is really simple.When you publish your web app, you have 2  choices - one, the script runs as 'you' and the other the script runs as the user running the script. Depending on how you set it up, the judges will either see an authorization message (script run as user) or see the script in action (when run as you). See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#permissions